# Binding Radio Button to Angular in C# cshtml

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I would like to pass the value of the **Radio button** along with the **ng-click** method in **C#**. How should I do that? I am binding the value of Resume into the **Modal** using **JavaScript**. I want to send the value of ResumeId with the userAlertResumeSubmit function.

**Following is my code for Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="ResumeModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="topCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplyJob", "PostedJob", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                          x
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Choose Your Resume</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="PostedJobId" id="PostedJobById" value="@Model.PostedJobId" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="CreatedBy" id="CreatedBy" value="@Model.CreatedBy" />
                            @foreach (var item in NurseOneStop.WebSite.Models.ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.NurseResumeList)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-12 lstCard">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="CheckedResumeId" id="CheckedResumeId" />
                                    <input type="radio" name="RBCheckedResume" style="height: 15px; width: 18px;" onchange="CheckedResume(@item.ResumeId)" /> <span>@item.ResumeName</span>
                                     </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        @*<label id="lblMessage" style="color:red"></label>*@

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btnSubmitResume" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="userAlertResumeSubmit()">
                        Submit
                </button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how Resume ID is bind into the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnShowModal").click(function (){
            $("#ResumeModal").modal('show');
        });
    });
    function CheckedResume(id) {
        $('#CheckedResumeId').val(id);
        //var IsAllow = ($('#CheckedResumeId').val());
        //alert('dddddddddddddddddddd' + IsAllow);
        console.log($('#CheckedResumeId').val());
    };
</script>
```

Comment: in your ng-click call a javascript method with ajax and pass what ever data you want as body of ajax. this way you can hit the server method with your data.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV can you help me with the code? I am new to Angular and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be more Jquery rather than angular ( Not a good practice)

So anyway you have a `ng-click="userAlertResumeSubmit()"` click method in your button so you can implement this method in javascript like below

```
var userAlertResumeSubmit= function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: place your server url,
        data:pass the data",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
           // if you want to do any action sin success then do it here 
        }
    });

}
```

Note :

If you want to stick with proper AngularJS(recommenced) then create a service method and call the server from service layer and pass the model item there.